# ASP.NET hyperlink in a IF statement?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, visual-studio-2013, hyperlink, session-variables

I currently have a asp hyperlink control that links to a login page and there is a button called sign out which clears the session variables. I was thinking of trying to clear the session variables with the hyperlink control without going to the login page. Is there any way I could do this maybe with an IF statement?

This is my code for the hyperlink control:

```
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="Log_out" Class="sign_up" visible="false" NavigateUrl="/Pages/login.aspx">Sign out</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinkButton` and clear the session before you redirect in the click-event? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7231659/284240

Comment: I see that's how you can do it in C# but how do you do it in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, you need this link's code in VB.NET (you only mentioned .NET): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231659/284240

If so, here it is.  Let us know if you are looking for something else.

```
Public Sub linkGoSomewhere_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

See this link for how to set onclick event in code behind:
[How to code a Button's Click Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446410/how-to-code-a-buttons-click-event)

Comment: I did mine slightly different but similar sort of idea, thank you, much appreciated.